# android expandable listView-About star ratings

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am making a content app in which there is a page displaying list of restaurants and its details wherein i have used Expandable listView.So in the child list i want to display two items i.e cuisine and ratings.I am stuck up with the ratings part.I am posting my code below.Please help me for this.

```
restaurant_pg.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:src="@drawable/eatery" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="Restaurants"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:gravity="center" />

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/restaurant_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >

</ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>



group_item.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/restaurant"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/map"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/map"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/mapicon" />
```

```
 child_item.xml

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/restaurant"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"       
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginRight="76dp"
    android:src="@drawable/staricon" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/staricon" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/staricon" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/staricon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView4"
    android:text="Star rating"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Cuisine -"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
    android:src="@drawable/staricon" />
```

Restaurant_pg.java

```
package com.example.myagraguide;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
 import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

  import com.example.myagraguide.ExpandableListAdapter.*;

  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
 import android.os.Build;

 public class Restaurant_pg extends Activity 
{

 List<String> groupList;
    List<String> childList;
    Map<String, List<String>> list_restaurants;
    ExpandableListView expListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.restaurant_pg);

        createGroupList();

        createCollection();

        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.restaurant_list);
        final ExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(
                this,list_restaurants, groupList );
        expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);





  }
    private void createGroupList()
    {
        groupList = new ArrayList<String>();
        groupList.add("Esphehan the Oberoi Amarvilas");
        groupList.add("Panchhi Petha Store");
        groupList.add("Pinch of Spice");
        groupList.add("Shankara Vegis Restaurant");
        groupList.add("Khandelaa");
        groupList.add("Mughal Room");
        groupList.add("Tandoori Nights");
        groupList.add("Taj Mahal Restaurant");
    }



/*   private OnGroupClickListener myListGroupClicked =  new OnGroupClickListener()
    {

          public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, long id) {

           //get the group header
           HeaderInfo headerInfo = deptList.get(groupPosition);   */


    private void createCollection() {
        // preparing restaurant details(child)
        String[] esphehan_detail = {"Indian" };
        String[] panchhi_detail={"Indian"};
        String[] pinch_of_spice={"Multi-cuisine "};
        String[] shankara={"Indian"};
        String[] khandela={"Mughalai"};
        String[] mughal_room={"Chinese"};
        String[] tandoori={"Tandoori"};
        String[] taj_mahal={"Multi-Cuisine "};


        list_restaurants=new LinkedHashMap<String,List<String>>();


        for(String restaurant:groupList)
        {
            if(restaurant.equals("Esphehan the Oberoi Amarvilas"))
            {
                loadChild(esphehan_detail);

                list_restaurants.put(restaurant,childList);
                }
            if(restaurant.equals("Panchhi Petha Store"))
            {
                loadChild(panchhi_detail);

                list_restaurants.put(restaurant,childList);
                }
            if(restaurant.equals("Pinch of Spice"))
            {
                loadChild(pinch_of_spice);

                list_restaurants.put(restaurant,childList);
                }
            if(restaurant.equals("Shankara Vegis Restaurant"))
            {
                loadChild(shankara);

                list_restaurants.put(restaurant,childList);
                }
            if(restaurant.equals("Khandelaa"))
            {
                loadChild(khandela);

                list_restaurants.put(restaurant,childList);
                }
            if(restaurant.equals("Mughal Room"))
            {
                loadChild(mughal_room);

                list_restaurants.put(restaurant,childList);
                }
            if(restaurant.equals("Tandoori Nights"))
            {
                loadChild(tandoori);

                list_restaurants.put(restaurant,childList);
                }
            if(restaurant.equals("Taj Mahal Restaurant"))
            {
                loadChild( taj_mahal);

                list_restaurants.put(restaurant,childList);
                }

            }


        }
    private void loadChild(String[] rest_detail) 
    {
        childList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String options : rest_detail)
            childList.add(options);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

     @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }


        }

   ExpandableListAdapter

     package com.example.myagraguide;

  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Map;

    import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.AlertDialog;
  import android.app.Dialog;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.DialogInterface;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.graphics.Typeface;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
   import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.PopupWindow;
   import android.widget.TextView;

  public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
private Activity context;
private Map<String, List<String>> list_restaurants;
private List<String> restaurants;





 public ExpandableListAdapter(Activity context,Map<String, List<String>>       list_restaurants,List<String> restaurants)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.list_restaurants=list_restaurants;
    this.restaurants=restaurants;
}



public Object getChild(int groupPosition,int childPosition)
{
    return list_restaurants.get(restaurants.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition,int childPosition)
{
    return childPosition;
}

public View getChildView(final int groupPosition,final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    final String restaurants = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    if (convertView == null) 
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
    }
    TextView tv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant) ;
//  return tv;

    tv.setText(restaurants);
    return convertView;

}

 public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
 {
        return list_restaurants.get(restaurants.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) 
    {
        return restaurants.get(groupPosition);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() 
    {
        return restaurants.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) 
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        String restaurantName = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item,
                    null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant);
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

    /*    ImageView contact=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact);

        contact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.contact_tajmahal);

                ImageView iv=(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.exitButton);

                iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

                dialog.show();



                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });     */



        /*{

           public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setMessage("Do you want to remove?");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                List<String> child = 
                                               list_restaurants.get(restaurants.get(groupPosition));
                              //  child.remove(childPosition);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });     */

        tv.setText(restaurantName);
        return convertView;
    }




    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried this tutorial ? http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: No.I refered this one: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/

Comment: in your row layout for the child view, add rating stars. then inside your adapter class handle the rating as you want

Comment: Handling it means like how?? Can you please guide me.I am new to this.

Comment: Please can somebody help me out for this. I am stuck up to this very badly.Please help.Thank you.